# mySQL query to count number of unique users posting to database

Tags: php, mysql

In a database we have about 1000 registered users. I'd like to know how many of those users have actually written a question or posted an answer. All the information can be take from the tblQA table and the userid is "intPosterID", the questions & answers each have their own ID, "PostID". Is there a query that can be run to count how many unique users have posted a question or answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counting the distinct userIDs can be done via:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT intPosterID ) FROM tblQA;
```

[`COUNT( DISTINCT field )`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) returns a count of the number of rows with different values for the given field - `intPosterID` in this case.

Comment: Getting Resource ID #11 error. $unique = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT intPosterID ) FROM tblQA)";

Comment: Does running the query give you the error, or are you trying to echo $unique? If the latter, it won't work as it's a Mysql resource, not a result yet. Try $res = mysql_query('QUERY_HERE'); $unique = mysql_fetch_row($res); print_r($unique);

Answer (score 1):

Count posts per user :

```
SELECT COUNT(PostID), intPosterID FROM tblQA GROUP BY intPosterId
```

numbers of results = number of  users or run ConroyP query

Answer (score 1):

COUNT(DISTINCT columnname) can be used for that :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT intPosterId) FROM tblQA;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
select count(intPosterID)
from tblQA
group by intPosterID;
```

Comment: this will return the number of non-null values in the column, not necessarily the number of different values.